# Best way to persist data?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a complex JSON which I need to persist over two POST requests. Currently i'm storing the serialized JSON in tempdata though the second post never succeeds before of Error 400(The size of headers is too long). In this image I viewed the cookies in Chrome Debugger
[image: Cookie Overflow]

Am I doing MVC wrong? The data is probably too complex to be stored in tempdata. However for this example this JSON is only 234 line(Unsure if this reflexes cookie size accurately). I know I could increase the size of the cookie but this wouldn't fix the real issues.

Should I be storing the data in a different method?

Basically in my project i'm posting a value to the controller(Many times via POST) which then uses the value to get a certain part of the JSON. Is Session the only alternative?

I'm still a novice to MVC so forgive me if i've made a simple mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `TempData` and `Session` are the same thing. The only difference is the length of persistence: in the former, just until the next request, while in the latter for the life of the session.

Second, session storage has to be configured. If you don't configure it, then something like `TempData` will attempt to use cookies to persist the data. Otherwise, it will use your session store. Basically, by using *any* actual session store, you should have no issues with the size of the data.

Third, you have not provided much information about what you're actually doing here, but for the most part, sessions (`Session` or `TempData`) are a poor choice for persistence. The data you're trying to store between requests does not sound like it is user-specific, which makes sessions a particular poor choice. Most likely, you want a distributed cache here, though you could potentially get by with an in-memory cache. You should also consider whether you need to persist this data *at all*. It's far too common to over-optimize by worrying about running the same query against at database, for example, multiple times. Databases are *designed* to efficiently retrieve large amounts of data, and properly set up, can handle many thousands of simultaneous queries without breaking a sweat. Ironically, sometimes a caching a query doesn't actually save you anything over actually running the query, especially with distributed caching mechanisms.

Simple is better than complex. Start simple. Solve the problem in the most straight-forward way possible. If that involves issuing the same query multiple times, do so. It doesn't matter. Then, once you have a working solution, profile. If it's running slower than you like, or starts to fall down when fielding 1000s of requests, *then* look into ways to optimize it by caching, etc. Developers waste an enormous amount of time and energy trying to optimize things that aren't actually even problems.